# TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have an Excel table in the following format:

[image]

I want to read this table with Python using the `pandas` modules and calculate the difference between an issue date and the current date. This is my current code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt
    def abc():
        a=pd.read_excel('date time.xlsx')
        b=dt.date.today()
        print(b)
        c=(a['date of issue'])
        h=(c[0])
        f=dt.datetime(h)
        d=b-f
        print(d)
   abc()
```

It is showing an error in line 7 (`f=dt.datetime(h)`). It reads `TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)`.

Answer (score 20):

The `datetime` module is part of the Python standard library. The constructor of the `datetime.datetime` class takes a specific year, month and day as parameter ([Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)). You would invoke it e.g. with `datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 8)`.

In your code you are querying a specific cell from a an Excel table via  the `pandas` library. This cell happens to contain a date, which `pandas` detects and turns into a `pandas.Timestamp` object. The `pandas` library is not part of the Python standard library, for this reason Python's `datetime` class does not know about `pandas.Timestamp`. When you pass a `pandas.Timestamp` to the `datetime` constructor, you get the error message `TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)`. This means `datetime` expected an integer (specifying the year), but received a `pandas.Timestamp`, which it does not understand.

However, `pandas` does know about `datetime` and offers you a helper function `to_pydatetime` to turn a `pandas.Timestamp` into a `datetime` object ([reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html?highlight=to_pydatetime#pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime)). In your code, replace the assignment for `f` with:

```
    f=h.to_pydatetime().date()
```

The `to_pydatetime()` gives you a `datetime.datetime` object, and then the `.date()` turns it into a `datetime.date` object, which is required for the `d=b-f` in the next line, as you assigned `b` with `datetime.date.today()`.

Alternatively, you could also change the declaration of `b` to `b=dt.datetime.now()` and then the assignment of `f` to `f=h.to_pydatetime()`. This would give you the precise time difference, not just the difference in days.